# checkbox in kivy RecycleView, clicking one impacts others

Tags: kivy

I try to put a group of two checkboxes in each row in RecycleView. But if I click one checkbox, some other checkboxes is impacted.
As the following pictures:

[click row 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpNen.png)

[row 13 is impacted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSFqQ.png)

So are the row 25, 37 ...
the following is the code

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Root(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Root, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rv.data = [{'value': str(x)} for x in range(100)]

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

my.kv:

```
<Row@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    value: ''

    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        text: root.value
        size_hint:0.45, 1
    CheckBox:
        group: root.value
        size_hint:0.05, 1
        state: 'down'
    CheckBox:
        group: root.value
        size_hint:0.05, 1
<Root>:
    rv: rv
    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        viewclass: 'Row'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
```

It's really simple code, but I don't know why.
Could you please help?

## kivy is 1.10.0

the root cause is that the viewclasses are recycled for reusing.
We can derive the viewclass from RecycleDataViewBehavior(have to read the code).
Implement refresh_view_attrs. Maybe add the state of checkboxes into data of recycleview. Can refer to the example of SelectableLabel in recycleview/**init**.py.

Comment: It seems that the same row on each page is impacted.

Comment: It's due to the recycling of viewclass. But I haven't found a graceful method to deal with it.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I've been working on a similar issue.